# creating new record in another table for each user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want to create a new record (row) in a different table in the data base.
the user is created in this method

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $confirmation_code = str_random(30);
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code,
    ]);
}
```

I want to add the created user id in another table. for example "addresses" table.

I tried doing it inside the create method but I don't know the new user ID!
how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
$confirmation_code = str_random(30);
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code,
]);
Address::create([
   ... 
   'user_id' => $user->id;
]);
return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = $data['name'];
...
$user->save();
// get new user ID with
$id = $user->id;
```